# Soap UI Mock service for Rest not working when deployed as war

Tags: rest, tomcat, mocking, soapui

I want to create SoapUI mock service for the endpoint: "/product/123456/details/". Here 123456 is path variable.
I have created a soap ui mock service with path as "/product/" and in response I'm just giving back the path(Just for testing).
When I run this mock service in SoapUI on port 8210, and hitting "http://localhost:8210/product/123456/details" works perfect. 
I get the below response.

```
"/product/123456/details"
```

But when I deploy this as mymockwar war in tomcat running on port 8080,
If I hit "http://localhost:8080/mymockwar/product/123456/details/",
Then I get the response as below.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>soapUI MockServices Log for project [MyNewMock]</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Log is disabled.</h3>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now if I hit "http://localhost:8080/mymockwar/product/" it works and gives me the response as

```
"/product/"
```

How can I make this working with path variable when deployed in tomcat?
Tomcat version: 7.0.22
SoapUI version: 4.5.2

Mock service xml below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<con:soapui-project xmlns:con="http://eviware.com/soapui/config" activeEnvironment="Default" name="MyNewMock" resourceRoot="" soapui-version="4.5.2" abortOnError="false" runType="SEQUENTIAL">
   <con:settings />
   <con:mockService port="8210" path="/product/" host="localhost" name="testSoapMock" bindToHostOnly="false" docroot="">
      <con:settings>
         <con:setting id="com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.WsdlMockService@require-soap-action">false</con:setting>
      </con:settings>
      <con:properties />
      <con:onRequestScript>def method = mockRequest.method;
def path = mockRequest.path;
log.info path
def response = mockRequest.getHttpResponse()
            response.setContentType("application/json")
            def writer = response.getWriter();
            writer.write(path)
            writer.close()</con:onRequestScript>
   </con:mockService>
   <con:properties />
   <con:wssContainer />
</con:soapui-project>
```

Comment: Is there any exception on tomcat logs?

Comment: No. No exception in logs

Answer (score 0):

I faced same exception and solution is the name in url and the name in xml request they should be the same or name conflict

Ex:

```
URL: http://localhost:8088/mocks/queryBalance

Request :<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <ns3:queryBalanceRequestMsg xmlns:ns2="http://www.huawei.com/bme/cbsinterface/cbscommon" xmlns:ns3="http://www.huawei.com/bme/cbsinterface/arservices" xmlns:ns4="http://cbs.huawei.com/ar/wsservice/arcommon">
      <requestHeader>
        <ns2:ownershipInfo>
          <ns2:beId>101</ns2:beId>
        </ns2:ownershipInfo>
        <ns2:accessSecurity>
          <ns2:loginSystemCode>ecare01</ns2:loginSystemCode>
          <ns2:password>Admin123!</ns2:password>
        </ns2:accessSecurity>
        <ns2:operatorInfo>
          <ns2:operatorId>9001</ns2:operatorId>
        </ns2:operatorInfo>
      </requestHeader>
      <queryBalanceRequest>
        <ns3:serviceNumber>1511661998</ns3:serviceNumber>
      </queryBalanceRequest>
    </ns3:queryBalanceRequestMsg>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

when URL was queryBalance it was return your exception